# How to calculate $\int{\frac{dx}{3x^2+2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've started doing $$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dx}{3x^2+2}}$$
but I only get
$$\displaystyle\int{(3x^2+2)^{-1}dx}\\
\frac{1}{6}\displaystyle\int{\frac{6x(3x^2+2)^{-1}}{x}dx}\\
$$
And I don't know how to do solve this.

Comment: Do you know residue theorem?

Comment: @Argon Why would you need residues here?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I find them easier to compute this integral then trigonometric substitutions.

Comment: @Argon But the OP is asking for a primitive, not a definite integral. How do residues play a role here?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I see.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If for the errors you mean to put indefinite integrals in the form of definite integrals doesn't matter. I've understand it and I think it's the correct answer. If I'm wrong, please, correct me.

Comment: @Garmen: There was a conflation of definite and indefinite integrals; currently, there is an error in not changing the interval of integration when doing a change of variable (in the second step). If you change everything to indefinite integrals and drop the interval $[a,b]$, then the result is incomplete/incorrect for two reason: (i) the problem is about a function of $x$, the answer is about a function of $t$; and (ii) it would be missing the constant of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we put $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x=t$ then it means that $\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\mathrm dt$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int{\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{3x^2+2}} &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int{\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x)^2+1}}\\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\int{\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{t^2+1}}\\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \arctan(t)+\text C\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\right)+\text C\\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\right)}+\text C
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Arturo and Abdelmajid: due to the large number of substantial edits, the answer has been converted to Community Wiki. I'm also purging all comments since it appears that they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint.** Do you know how to integrate
$$\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du\ ?$$
If so, can you make a change of variable, say $u=kx$ for some constant $k$, so that $3x^2+2 = 2u^2+2 = 2(u^2+1)$?

Comment: For integration like this, if you can imagine a "sum of squares" or "difference of squares" it could suggest a right triangle, and then a trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dx}{3x^2+2}}$$

put $x =\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}.\tan \theta $

$$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}. (\sec\theta)^2. d\theta}{2+2(\tan\theta)^2}}$$

$$\sqrt\frac{1}{6}\displaystyle\int{d\theta}=\sqrt\frac{1}{6}\theta+c=\sqrt\frac{1}{6}.\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\right)}+c$$